# For de un json para consumir un servicio

Tags: go

Tengo un json (jsonData) en el siguiente formato:

```json
[
   {"id":"87238"},
   {"id":"87335"},
   {"id":"87348"},
   {"id":"87378"},
   {"id":"87388"}
]
```

Tengo que iterar dicho json y extraer el id para consumir un servicio pero no se bien como hacer el for, tengo lo siguiente pero no me funciona:

```
countJson := len(jsonData)

for i := 0; i < countJson; i++ {

    resp, err := http.Get("https://www.pokemon.com/receipt?id=%s&certificateId=0", jsonData)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(resp)
}
```

me responde un error

```
too many arguments
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este es tu json completo?

Supongo que estas recibiendo algo del estilo

```
{ "ids" : [
   {"id":"87238"},
   {"id":"87335"},
   {"id":"87348"},
   {"id":"87378"},
   {"id":"87388"}
],

"bla": "bla"

}
```

Lo que te recomiendo es unmarshallear ese json e iterar sobre estos elementos.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {

    jsonData := `[{"id":"1234"},{"id":"2345"},{"id":"3456"}]`
    ids := make([]map[string]string, 10)
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonData), &ids); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    for _, value := range ids {
        url := fmt.Sprintf("https://www.pokemon.com/receiptid=%s&certificateId=0", value["id"])
        resp, err := http.Get(url)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(resp)
    }

}
```

No olvides utilizar fmt.Sprintf() para concatenar el id a la url de la manera que quieres.